# Sorting Using Linq Where list contains alphabets and Numerics

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Imagine that I have a string list or custom list in which one of the string field contains following data

> A 5 D 3 1 B 2 4 C

How to Sort this list so that the output would be

> A B C D 1 2 3 4 5

where as `Orderby` Gives the following answer

> 1 2 3 4 5 A B C D

Answer (score 2):

Much simpler method:

```
string inputString = "A5D31B24C";
var Output = inputString.OrderBy(x => Char.IsDigit(x)).ThenBy(x=>x).ToList();
```

The First `OrderBy` will sort the list like this : `ABCD53124`, this is because the OrderBy will evaluate boolean values in the order of `false` then `true`. The following `ThenBy` will give you the expected result which is `ABCD12345`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below LINQ which sorts the list by alphabetic value and then by numeric value:

```
 var result = list.OrderByDescending(x => x.All(char.IsLetter))
     .ThenByDescending(x => x.Any(char.IsDigit))
     .ThenBy(x => x)
     .ToList();
```

Comment: Give me a runtime error saying  At least one object must implement IComparable.

Comment: because compiler doesn't know how to compare your values and perform the ordering.Your type must implement IComparable

Answer (score 0):

Use `OrderBy` like this:

```
List<char> str = new List<char>{'A' ,'5' ,'D', '3', '1' ,'B' ,'2' ,'4' ,'C'};
//Or string str = "A5D31B24C";
var sorted = str.OrderBy(c => char.IsLetter(c) ? 0 : 1).ThenBy(c => c).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be giving priority to letters.

```
list.OrderBy(x=> char.IsDigit(x)? 255+x : x);
```